# how to set the LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH for the zerobrane studio in linux

Tags: linux, lua, zerobrane

I want to add a module path for all of my project in zerobrane.  I add following code into the user.lua.

```
LUA_PATH=LUA_PATH .. ';mypath'  or
package.path=package.path .. ';mypath'
```

It can't work. how can I do it ?

**PS**
I don't want to set the package.path at the begin of all the project.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I add following method into the `/opt/zbsstudio/lualibs/mobdebug/mobdebug.lua` file.

```
package.path = package.path .. ';my_path/?/init.lua'
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ';my_path/?.so'
```

But I'm not sure that's the best way.

Comment: If you are not sure why is this an accepted answer?

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit files which are part of some software. They'll be overwritten next time you upgrade or reinstall the software and you would have to re-apply those changes every time you do that.

Answer (score 25):

When Lua starts, it initialises `package.path` and `package.cpath` with values of `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` environment variables. Setting up these environment variables will be one clean way to set paths. Appending `LUA_PATH`'s value with a double semi-colon will make Lua append the default path to the specified path.

Using bash on Linux, you can set the paths by adding these lines to the end of `~/.bashrc` file. For example:

```
## final ;; ensure that default path will be appended by Lua
export LUA_PATH="<path-to-add>;;"
export LUA_CPATH="./?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;
                /usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?.so;<path-to-add>"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried setting LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH through bash.bashrc.local and it is set which I made sure by using echo in terminal. But, my lua scripts still cannot find some modules. Here is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865886/modifying-haproxy-lua-library-path

Answer (score 0):

You can set `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` before starting ZeroBrane Studio and it should pass those values to all the projects you run or debug from the IDE.

Comment: How to set. can you make an example